# php showing multiple echo when retrieving from the database

Tags: php, mysql

Hiii, I am getting multiple value form database when I am using foreach, plz help

```
function display($host,$user,$pass,$database)
      {
        $db = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass); 
        mysql_select_db ($database);        
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `sysdes_moduleinfo`"; 
        $result = mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error()); 
        $i=0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
            /*$max = count($row);
            while($i<6) {
            echo $row[$i]." ";
            $i++;
            }*/
            foreach ($row as $value)
            {
                //echo $value . " ";
                echo htmlspecialchars($value);
             }
            echo "<br/>";
        }
```

This what I get with this code.
[image].

This what I have in the database.
[image]

Comment: You shouldn't use mysql_* functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5, use mysqli or PDO instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
       foreach ($row as $value)
       {
           //echo $value . " ";
           echo htmlspecialchars($value);
       }
       echo "<br/>";
 }
```

`mysql_fetch_array` returns both a numeric and associative array.

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc() can be used too.

Comment: @RichardA Yes.Should be use `mysql_fetch_assoc()`

Answer (score 5):

The default result type for mysql_fetch_array is to return data in both a number and associative array.
This is why data is duplicated. Try using mysql_fetch_row instead.

However it should be noted that both mysql_fetch_array & mysql_fetch_row are both deprecated.

Comment: Just the associative array will do aswell.

Comment: Thx, It started working for me now. If mysql_fetch_array is deprecated then what should I use;